# play youtube video in your flash swf

Tags: flash, audio, video, stream, youtube

I am trying to create a web app that play youtube videos (or atleast audio of the videos) inside a SWF which im trying to create. Does flash have the class needed to read youtube stream and play it and give me the posibility to show the percent of video loaded and where the play position is?

Thank you, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference).